# Error with queries with more than 2 union statements access

Tags: ms-access

I am having this problem with union queries. When I try to use more than 2 UNION statements I gate this error - "The microsoft access database engine could not find the object ". Make sure the object name exists and that you spell its path name correctly." 
The SQL code is:

```
    SELECT [Pt data 1].IDno, [Pt data 1].pt_name, [Expected visit date modified].[Visit day], [Expected visit date modified].[Visit Time], [Pt data 1].[visit_14d_st] AS Status
    FROM [Expected visit date modified] INNER JOIN [Pt data 1] ON [Expected visit date modified].IDno = [Pt data 1].IDno
    WHERE ((([Expected visit date modified].[Visit Time])="Day 14") AND (Not ([Pt data 1].[visit_14d_st])="Data Entered" And Not ([Pt data 1].[visit_14d_st])="Missed Visit"));
    UNION 
    SELECT [Pt data 1].IDno, [Pt data 1].pt_name, [Expected visit date modified].[Visit day], [Expected visit date modified].[Visit Time], [Pt data 1].[visit_28d_st] AS Status
    FROM [Expected visit date modified] INNER JOIN [Pt data 1] ON [Expected visit date modified].IDno = [Pt data 1].IDno
    WHERE ((([Expected visit date modified].[Visit Time])="Day 28") AND (Not ([Pt data 1].[visit_28d_st])="Data Entered" And Not ([Pt data 1].[visit_28d_st])="Missed Visit"));
    UNION 
    SELECT [Pt data 1].IDno, [Pt data 1].pt_name, [Expected visit date modified].[Visit day], [Expected visit date modified].[Visit Time], [Pt data 1].[visit_42d_st] AS Status
    FROM [Expected visit date modified] INNER JOIN [Pt data 1] ON [Expected visit date modified].IDno = [Pt data 1].IDno
    WHERE ((([Expected visit date modified].[Visit Time])="Day 42") AND (Not ([Pt data 1].[visit_42d_st])="Data Entered" And Not ([Pt data 1].[visit_42d_st])="Missed Visit"));
```

The issue is that the query works fine with any of the two queries but not with all three. I am totally stuck with this. Any help please. Thanks.

Comment: Is everything in MS Access or are you linking tables from another database?

Comment: Do each of these unions and/or selects work independently? i.e. there are no spelling mistakes?

Comment: sorry for the delay in reply.....All the tables are in access. all the unions and queries work independently.

Answer (score 0):

UNION queries can be tough to read, and tough to check for typos. I would suggest you put each of the statements into saved queries (e.g. "qryVisit_Day14", "qryVisit_Day28"). Then make your UNION query look like this:

```
      SELECT * FROM qryVisit_Day14
UNION SELECT * FROM qryVisit_Day28
UNION SELECT * FROM qryVisit_Day42
```